# Webpack ExtractTextPlugin multiple Less files to multiple CSS files

Tags: css, webpack, less, extract-text-plugin

All examples I find, sends to one file, but I would like to:

/style/foo.less to /style/foo.css

It should put the css in same folder as the less it finds.